# Is it possible to bend a linear gradient CSS?

Tags: css, linear-gradients, radial-gradients, css-gradients

I am trying to create this "swoosh" through the image with CSS.

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JHvD.jpg (without gradient)
I have tried doing this with a radial gradient, however, I can't get the gradient to "shut off" abruptly, as the gradient approaches the center. Would the best approach to this be to somehow bend a liner gradient?

This is what I have so far, I don't want the blue to be in the corner, I just want a "slice" of the gradient running down the image.
https://jsfiddle.net/uh882Lcw/

HTML

```
<div class="banner-image">
  <div class="glint">

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.glint {
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 80%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: -700px;
    left: 250px;
    width: 1300px;
    height: 1060px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.banner-image {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/960x361');
    width: 960px;
    height: 361px;
    position: relative;
    }
```

Comment: "I have tried doing this with a radial gradient", please include this code that you've tried, as it's the appropriate solution, it sounds like you were close.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [radial gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) on top of a background image.

```css
.bg-img {
  width: 620px;
  height: 200px;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse 800% 500% at 425% -25%, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%), url(http://lorempixel.com/620/200/animals);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to just make the gradient a "slice"? it looks like the gradient is  still affecting the right side of the image

Comment: You mean that the right side should be transparent?

Comment: Yes, I believe to achieve this I have to set the origin to be at the top right hand corner of the image.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, then you just want that center bit a little more transparent. You can tweak the percentages and transparencies to get the effect you want then.

```css
.glint {
    background: radial-gradient(
      transparent 10%,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 80%);
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: -700px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 1300px;
    height: 1060px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.banner-image {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/OFFk8obg.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 700px;
  height: 361px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-image">
  <div class="glint"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another try

I am using border radius to limit the part affected by the gradient; I needed a div greater than the container to achieve the proper shape

```css
.test {
  height: 400px;
  width: 1090px;
  border: solid 1px green;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.test:after {
  content: "";
  width: 96%;
  height: 177%;
  right: -10%;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1374px 876px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0.4), rgba(0,0,0,0.3));
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```